# Apache Zeppelin - Angular Display system load external Angular modules

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, apache-zeppelin

How would it be possible to register new Angular modules in Zeppelin:

Based on this Angular example

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/getting-started

Here is the possible converted code in Zeppelin (the same code works fine in a standard webapp)

```js
print(s"""%angular
<div id="myAngularApp">
    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Angular Material Button</md-button>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.22/require.js"></script>

<script>
    require.config({
    paths: {
        'angular': 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min',
        'ngAnimate': 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.min',
        'ngAria': 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-aria.min',
        'ngMaterial': 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min'
    },
    shim: {
        'ngAnimate': ['angular'],
        'ngAria': ['angular'],
        'ngMaterial': {
             deps: ['ngAnimate', 'ngAria']
         }
    }
});

require([ 'angular', 'ngMaterial' ], function () {
    var app = angular.module('StarterApp', ['ngMaterial']);
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('myAngularApp'), ['StarterApp']);
    return app;
});
</script>
""")
```

Unfortunately, I didn't find any ways to make it work. I tried with multiple ways, nothing works!

In brief, **how to register a new Angular Module within Zeppelin?**

The Angular Display system looks nice but is useless if no external modules can easily be registered.

Please, help :) Or provide a concrete example